# How to fix duplicate tag name in php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't know how to explain it, maybe this is understandable. I have 2 table:

1. Table tags: (tagID: '1', '2', '3') (tagName: 'a', 'b', 'b')
2. Table tag_posts: (postID: '1', '1', '2') (tagID: '1', '2', '3')

> **Output:** Post 1 tagged (a[id=1], b[id=2]) and post 2 tagged (b[id=3])

But, i want result like this:

1. Table tags: (tagID: '1', '2') (TagName: 'a', 'b')
2. Table tag_posts: (postID: '1', '1', '2') (tagID: '1', '2',
       '2')

> **Output:** Post 1 tagged (a[id=1], b[id=2]) and post 2 tagged (b[id=2])

I want on table "tags" tag name, b is 2; not b = 2 and b = 3 (not double tag name)

Php

```
$last_post_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);

foreach($tags as $tag){
  $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tb_tags WHERE tagName = '$tag'") or die(mysqli_error());
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
  if($row == NULL){
    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO tb_tags (tagName) VALUES ('$tag')") or die(mysqli_error());
    $last_tag_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO tb_tag_posts (postID, tagID) VALUES ('$last_post_id', '$last_tag_id')") or die(mysqli_error());
  }else{
  // if tags name exists do nothing and take the existing id tag
    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO tb_tag_posts (postID, tagID) VALUES ('$last_post_id', '".$row['tagID']."')") or die(mysqli_error());
  }
}
```

Comment: For reference, people who frequent the MySQL tag here expect to see _tabular_ sample data, rather than what you have posted above.  Please try to make your question more clear if possible.

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here but maybe you need a constraint on your table so the tag must be unique.

Comment: Before adding a new tag, you could simply search the tags table for a tag that has the same name. If you don't find any, insert the new tag and use that id. If it does exist, use the existing  id instead.

Comment: i update my question

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson do you have a link for instructions? or keywords on google?

Comment: The easy, but slightly aggressive way is to make the column unique in SQL. That way, SQL won't allow you to double post.

Otherwise, run a SQL select for the tag, and only if not found, allow for the new row to be inserted.

Comment: See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/ `ALTER TABLE tags
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_tags UNIQUE (tagName);` that will make it so mysql wont allow dups. Handle client side how you want to display that information.

Comment: It's just one SELECT query with `WHERE tagName = 'theTagName'`. If you get a result, then the tag exist and you can reuse that tag. If it doesn't exist, you do an INSERT for the new tag (which you already should have the code for). Not sure what more "instructions" you need for that before you try?

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_fetch_array:
`Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows for the resultset represented by the result parameter.` from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

I think that you need to have your code like this: `if($row == null){`

Comment: I update my code, can you correct? i want create tags, `ex. b is (id=2), c is (id=3), .. etc. But not b is (id=2), b is (id=3), b is (id=4), and c is (id=5), c is (id=6)`